# Specflow cannot process special characters

Tags: c#, binding, specflow, gherkin, feature-file

I'm trying to check DB entries using feature files in specflow an it doesn't seem to work.
Instead of reading the DB entry (that contains special characters (µ,ß,ä...), Specflow recognises characters such as µ,ß,ä as little '?'.

Is there any kind of package or plugin I can use to solve the issue or do I have to convert the characters within the step definition?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you seeing the question mark characters? We need more information before we can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

To handle those characters you can use [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). Basically, let's say you get you get `ä` from DB then you can use `\u00E4` to validate the text. Find relevant unicode from the link and assert using it.

Basically, the code will look as follows,

> Assert.Equals(dbstring, '\u00E4');